# Sheet Query formula giving the incorrect output

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet where the query formula used is very simple.

[Here is the test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i1d33KBY_pjDQ_n146QBqWPojZjvXmV9QUYBCZ5-asc/copy)

It just have to display the conetents of the second sheet in the first. Unfortunately, at some point the cell values are merged into single cells.

The example below shows till Apple1 to Apple 10 the data is merged in row 1.

I need a reason for this error and please avoid answering like, delete the row 15 of fruits tab sheet to correct.

Any cause for this is really appreciated.

Sheet2

[image]

Sheet1

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QUERY has several arguments. If you don't include them, they are assumed to be defaults (with the third argument being to try to make the first row into a header). Try this instead:

```
=query(Fruits!A3:F,"Select *",0)
```

or you can leave the middle argument blank in your case:

```
=query(Fruits!A3:F,,0)
```